# For OAuth, does the protected resource belong to the authorization server always?

Tags: c#, oauth, openid, identity

I have been reading about OAuth and OpenID quite a lot and get the part that OAuth protocol is an authorization protocol and not an authentication protocol.
So if the Authorization Server in OAuth has the right to generate Access tokens for a Protected resource that might be hosted on a separate server, does that mean that the protected resource belongs to the same party as the OpenId Provider or OAuth Server?

Can the Protected Resource belong to some other organization. If yes, is there a standardized protocol by which the protected resource server validates the Access Token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) (OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection) is the standard way.

Comment: Thanks. It does answer the second part of my question regarding the way the protected resource communicates with the authorization server.